# Why am I getting "There are no more files" error in the line "<packaging>war</packaging>" of my pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml, packaging

I have a Java Spring MVC project. The pom.xml looks like below:

[pom.xml snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ECh8.png)

It is giving error at the line: <packaging>war</packaging> as below:
*There are no more files (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources:default-resources:process-resources)*

May I know how can I fix this error? I have never faced this error before.

[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrg0M.png)

I have tried cleaning, Maven update etc. but with no luck.

Without this error fixed, I am unable to build my project.

Comment: Please, do not post snapshots of code and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Pino when adding the code (pom.xml) it was giving error as if it's a spam.